# How to pass a class type from SL app to SL library?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm building a custom panel to draw a tree in SL, the solution has one SL app project and one SL library project (this is where the panel code is).  The connections between the nodes are usercontrols in the library project. What I want to do is to have the connections in the SL app project then pass the type of the connections to the tree library, this way the tree connections are customizable by the user without having access to the library project.

I tried the following:

```
// pass the type of the connections in the constructor in the SL app project
var TC = new TreeContainer(typeof(TopToBottomConnectors.OffsetConnector),
                           typeof(TopToBottomConnectors.StraightConnector));
.....
// in the SL library, in the measure method
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(TopToBottomOffsetConnectorType.GetType());
// this line throws this exception: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

Any ideas or suggestion are very much appreciated.

**Update:**
There's a parameterless constructor, here's the class:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Graph.SL.LeftToRightConnectors
{
    public partial class OffsetConnector : UserControl
    {
        public OffsetConnector()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you not exposing a Template property on your Tree? that way the usage of the control could set the template of the nodes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using the template property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a parameterless constructor in your TopToBottomOffsetConnector class, or pass in the parameters that your constructor is expecting.

[Activator.CreateInstance on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d49ss92b.aspx)

Comment: There's a parameterless constructor, in fact that's what the connector class looks like:

'    public partial class OffsetConnector : UserControl
    {
        public OffsetConnector()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}'

Comment: Sounds like Activator might not be able to resolve the Type then. Take a look at this post and see if it helps: http://silverlightips.net/2010/02/28/using-activator-class-in-silverlight/

Comment: In debugging I see the namespace plus the class name, it's correct: Graph.SL.TopToBottomConnectors.OffsetConnector

Comment: In your sample namespace is Graph.SL.LeftToRightConnectors

Comment: Yes, I have both Graph.SL.LeftToRightConnectors and Graph.SL.LeftToRightConnectors and in both cases it's giving the same exception.